# To decompress a already gzip compressed x3d file (.x3d.gz)

Tags: xmlhttprequest, http-headers, gzip, x3d

I've an already gzip compressed x3d file (.x3d.gz) to load 3d model for my webpage. Since the x3d file size is big, i've gzipped it. Now how can i decompress it in the browser when the user loads this page? is it through http request header? if yes, how to execute this?

Comment: pretty much all browsers support gzip compression. Just make sure you enable deflate for the content type, upload the uncompressed x3d and you should be fine.

Comment: @Gamification I've two questions here. 1) if I enable deflate for content encoding in the server side, does it compresses only the html,css, js file or all types of files related to web page (x3d in this case) 2) How can i check whether particularly the x3d file is getting compressed or not